# How can I add values with the same "account title" and display this in my gridview using vb.net / aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

This is the source grid view with a sql datasource named trialbalance.

[image]

Output gridview should look like this.

[image]

Comment: what you are try just show it. ideally you can group by account title and code will get you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this :

```
Declare @t table(AccountTitle varchar(50) , Objectcode varchar(50) , Debit int, Credit int)

insert into @t values ('Petty Cash', '10101020-00' , 400, 0),

('Petty Cash', '10101020-00' , 100, 0),
('Cash in Bank', '10101030-00' , 400, 50),
('Cash in Bank', '10101030-00' , 50, 0),
('Cash in Bank', '10101030-00' , 100, 100)

select AccountTitle, Objectcode, sum(debit), sum(credit) from @t
group by AccountTitle, Objectcode
```

And output will be

```
AccountTitle    Objectcode  Debit   Credit
Petty Cash      10101020-00 500     0
Cash in Bank    10101030-00 550     150
```

Comment: thanks, but im currently experiencing conversion issues - converting nvarchar to decimal(Debit and Credit). i have try cast  and convert but is not working...

Comment: it means debit, credit is your nvarchar field. Right? if yes, then it is bad structure. try to change datattype to numberic(18,2) or decimal first. if do not want this, then it means you have a string value in your debit credit columns. remove it or give sample data.